# Why does my inline asp.net not working within <link href>?

Tags: asp.net, web-applications, versioning

I want to add a version number to my js files.

```
<link href="css/reset.min.css?v=<%= App.Golbal.VERSION %>" media="all" rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

This renders as

```
<link href="css/reset.min.css?v=&lt;%= App.Golbal.VERSION %>" media="all" rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

[Standard asp.net 4 web applciation]

Can anybody help?

Comment: Looks like <link></link> is html encoding your values. Is there a reason you aren't just using an anchor?

Comment: I think this is the <link> tag in the head section, not an anchor for linking.

Answer (score 13):

Put it inside PlaceHolder control because link in the title not included in the form tag so no parsing will occur to it as following

```
<asp:PlaceHolder runat="server">
<link href="css/reset.min.css?v=<%= App.Golbal.VERSION %>" media="all" rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</asp:PlaceHolder>
```

Answer (score 2):

As Dante suggests above, maybe change

```
<%= App.Golbal.VERSION %>
```

to

```
<%=App.Golbal.VERSION%>
```

or

```
<%=App.Global.VERSION%>
```

and try that.

Alternatively, like William suggest, set id and runat=server on the link element and apply the value in the server script/code behind.

```
<link id="lnkCSS" runat="server" media="all" rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

and the server script/code behind, something like

```
//might need HtmlLink lnkCSS = FindControls("lnkCSS")`
lnkCSS.href = "css/reset.min.css?`v=" + App.Global.VERSION;
```

Answer (score 1):

I've had similar issues before the way to get around it is make the link an asp:hyperlink and build the link in the code behind and then assign the link to the NavigateURL of the hyperlink.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try removing the white space in "<%= App.Golbal"?
Btw, Global is mispelled :)